# Determine Array include value in Another Array

Tags: javascript

I want to check if arr1 include arr2

i have try use .some and includes but it not return the right answer for me

```
arr1=[{Name:'John',Age:18},{Name:'Leona',Age:19},{Name:'Steve',Age:'21'}]
arr2=[{Name:'John',Age:18},{Name:'Hana',Age:19},{Name:'Josh',Age:20}]
```

my expected

```
arr1=[{Name:'John',Age:18},{Name:'Leona',Age:19},{Name:'Steve',Age:'21'},{Name:'Hana',Age:19},{Name:'Josh',Age:20}]
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking for someone to write the code for you. It'll be better if you post any solutions you've tried since SO is not for people to write the code for you.

Comment: So which one is it? You want the output to be just a `true` or `false` OR you want to merge the arrays?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: i have updated , so sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#every` with `array#some`. Iterate through each object in `arr2` and check if the object exist in `arr1`.

```js
let arr1=[{Name:'John',Age:18},{Name:'Leona',Age:19}],
    arr2=[{Name:'John',Age:18}],
    result = arr2.every(({Name, Age}) => {
      return arr1.some(o => o.Name === Name && o.Age === Age);
    });
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they are not the same object just objects with same values you have to compare each value.

```js
const arr1 = [{
  Name: 'John',
  Age: 18
}, {
  Name: 'Leona',
  Age: 19
}];
const arr2 = [{
  Name: 'John',
  Age: 18
}];

const check = arr1.some(e1 => arr2.some(e2 => e1.Name === e2.Name && e1.Age === e2.Age));
console.log(check);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the first array and check if `Name` is not in the first array, then add it to the result set.

```js
var array1 = [{ Name: 'John', Age: 18 }, { Name: 'Leona', Age: 19 }, { Name: 'Steve', Age: '21' }],
    array2 = [{ Name: 'John', Age: 18 }, { Name: 'Hana', Age: 19 }, { Name: 'Josh', Age: 20 }];

array2.reduce((r, o) => {
    if (!r.some(({ Name }) => o.Name === Name)) r.push(o);
    return r;
}, array1);

console.log(array1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```